# Specman e coverage: ignored values appear in the coverage statistics

Tags: specman, e

I need to collect a coverage only when one of the items has a specific value (only when `size == BYTE`). The code I wrote:

```
item size           : size_t       = trans.size using no_collect;
item byte_alignment : uint(bits:2) = trans.addr using no_collect;

cross size, byte_alignment using ignore = (size != BYTE);
```

In the test I run, `size != BYTE`, but I still have the `cross_size__byte_alignment` item in the coverage statistics with zero Overall Average Grade.. Why?

How to prevent collecting coverage for `size != BYTE`?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the "when" option on the item/cross to say *when* you want to collect coverage.
use the "ignore" option to *remove* buckets from the item/cross.

if you want to collect only when size *equals* BYTE and you do *not* want to see the buckets where size is *not* BYTE, combine both options:

```
cross size, byte_alignment using ignore = (size != BYTE), when = (size == BYTE);
```